# Spatial query in PostgreSQL to find a route to a specific point?

Tags: spatial-database

I drew 2 shapefiles - point.shp and line.shp. Line.shp has some lines intersecting points in point.shp. I converted the shapefile to PostgreSQL, but how can I make a spatial query to select a line from one point to another point ?

Comment: "to select a line from one point to another point" isn't a very clear question.

Comment: sorry, I mean how to find the rout between two location with spatial query.

Comment: Do you need to simply create a "straight line" between the 2 points.  As in, to determine the distance, or do you need to follow road segments or other linear features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this from memory, but it should be as simple as this. Replace the_geom with the name of your geometry column.

> SELECT a.line FROM a where ST_Intersects(a.the_geom, b.the_geom)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a topology.  In this case a topology in the form of a graph.  You can use pgRouting (http://pgrouting.org/) in order to achieve that.  Take a look at http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/.

Also, you will need to break those lines at the points.  pgRouting needs the begin point and the endpoint of each line.  I think you will find out this by yourself.